# Storing settings for Browser Helper Object

Tags: windows, settings, configuration-files, bho, browser-plugin

I have a browser helper object on IE that have some "clipboard history" functions. I have been storing settings into a file into the directory where the BHO file is (currently "$PROGRAMFILES\Common files\folder\", it was like this when i received the code but i can change it).

In my computer (XP SP3 in virtual machine) I have no problems writing the settings file, but I was wondering it this could cause "writing permission" problems in other computers and if it does what other method should I use to make sure it will work on all Windows computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could definitely have permission problems.  I would store the file in an appropriate subfolder under the "Application Data" or "Local Settings\Application Data" in user's profile folder.  The user running it should always have write permissions to those folders.

Comment: Files inside App Data wont get wipe out when cleaning tmp files doesnt it?

Comment: @jarkam.  That is correct.  They don't get wiped out when cleaning temp files.